# I need assistance with my SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm unable to run a query to get data what I want.

I wrote this code

```
SELECT C.topic, C.lastupdate, C.[MONTHN], SUM(CAST(C.Number AS Int)) FROM
(SELECT B.topic, B.lastupdate, B.[MONTHN], COUNT(B.[MONTHN]) as Number FROM
(SELECT A.topic, A.lastupdate, DATENAME(month,lastupdate) as [MONTHN] FROM
(SELECT topic, lastupdate from DACHFAQ) AS A) as B) AS C 
GROUP BY C.topic, C.lastupdate, C.[MONTHN];
```

but the MS Server is telling that

> Column 'B.topic' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I don't know how to correct this issue.

I Need to get data in such order:
Topic (Distinct), Month (Distinct), Sum of updates in that Month

**I'm new in SQL thats why I'm asking for help,**

Thank you for your comments here I place the solution: 
like ADyson wrote I needed to add a Groupby clause

```
SELECT C.topic, C.[MONTHN], SUM(Number) FROM
(SELECT B.topic, B.lastupdate, B.[MONTHN], COUNT(B.[MONTHN]) as Number FROM
(SELECT A.topic, A.lastupdate, DATENAME(month,lastupdate) as [MONTHN] FROM
(SELECT topic, lastupdate from DACHFAQ) AS A) as B
GROUP BY B.topic, B.lastupdate, B.[MONTHN]) as C 
GROUP BY C.topic, C.[MONTHN];
```

Thank your for your Support!

Comment: Not sure but I think `SELECT B.topic, B.lastupdate, B.[MONTHN], COUNT(B.[MONTHN])` will need its own GROUP BY clause, as will the next line too

Comment: Can you post table schema? I believe you only have one table named `DACHFAQ`?

Comment: Hi Yes there is only one Table Name DACHFAQ

Comment: Are you just wanting the count of updates in each month?

Comment: I suggest doing one thing at a time.  Get this to work, `SELECT topic, lastupdate from DACHFAQ`.  Then work your way outwards, step by step until you get it right.

Comment: Yes I Need the count of updates in each Month

Comment: Thank you ADyson it worked :)

Comment: If you want the count of updates each month, then @JohnPasquet's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not overly clear what you are wanting, but if what you want is Topic, Month, Total Number of Updates, then this might be what you want:

```
SELECT Topic, 
    DATENAME(month,lastupdate) as [MONTHN], 
    COUNT(*)
FROM DACHFAQ
GROUP BY Topic, DATENAME(month,lastupdate)
```

Now, you may need to account for the year as well.

Comment: Thank you, the code do the same :) Nice to know that there is other way!